# Floating div goes down when page is resized

Tags: css, html

Ok, so I have a 3 column floating divs. All are set `float:left`

1. Left div has fixed width
2. Middle div resizes with window
3. Right div has a fixed width

Everything looks fine 'til I resize the window  and the RIGHT `div` goes down below the middle `div`

[image]

[image]

and here are some code snippets

```
<div class="divContainer" style="width:300px;">
    <div class="divContent">
{RIGHT DIV CONTENT HERE}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="divContainer" style="min-width:600px;max-width: 65%">
    <div class="divContent">
{CENTER DIV CONTENT HERE}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="divContainer" style="width:265px;">
    <div class="divContent">
{RIGHT DIV CONTENT HERE}
    </div>
</div>

.divContent{    
    margin : 16px 10px 5px;
}

.divContainer {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;   
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    box-shadow:4px 4px 13px #bbbbbb;
    -moz-box-shadow:4px 4px 13px #bbbbbb;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Managed to come up with this but there's a gap between the middle `div` and the right `div` and I can't fill it without making the right `div` go down. I can't resize the middle higher than 63% and SO weird...

```
body min-width = 1560px
<div class="divContainer" style="width:300px;">
    <div class="divContent">
{RIGHT DIV CONTENT HERE}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="divContainer" style="min-width:900px;width: 63%;">
    <div class="divContent">
{CENTER DIV CONTENT HERE}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="divContainer" style="min-width:100px;max-width: 15%;float: right">
    <div class="divContent">
{RIGHT DIV CONTENT HERE}
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!!!**
I floated the first div to the left, the second one the to the right and the middle last no floats just margins based on right and left div width + padding+ margins

[image]

```
<div class="divContainer" style="width:300px;float: left;">
    <div class="divContent">[LEFT DIV StUFF HERE]</div>
</div>

<div class="divContainer" style="width: 250px;float: right;">
    <div class="divContent">[RIGHT DIV STUFF HERE]</div>
</div>

<div class="divWidget" id="clientStatusDiv" style="margin:0px 270px 0 310px;">
    <div class="divContent">[CENTER STUFF HERE]</div>
</div>
```

YAY!!! lol it even works when resize looks nice!!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the 65% width of the middle div is for the whole document and when the document is resized the middle div gets rezised so that it overlaps the right dif, forcing it to move down.

I think this should work for the middle div:
<div class="divContainer" style="min-width:600px;max-width: 90% - 565px">

I havn´t tried it out myself but i think that should work and if not, just try to lower the precentage from 90% to something smaller.

EDIT:
If you want to be able to make the window shorter than 565px wide you can try and set:

BODY {min-width:600px; }

Comment: subtracting from % o.o? dint think of that unfortunately if just puts both middle and right div below the first one =(

Comment: Try subtracting a little more, say 600 or so and maybe even change 90% to 70%.
Not sure if it will work but if you mess around with the values a bit i dont se why it shouldn´t work :)

Comment: and by the way, if min-width of middle-div is 600 then you should add that together with the width of the other 2 div´s width and also any potential padding and so forth so when i think of it i would set BODY { min-width: 1200 }

Comment: if that solved your problem please mark this post as the answer. :)

Comment: I manage to sort of fix it but thers a gap when screen is a bigger resolutions.
check revised code in first post

Answer (score 2):

Give max-width for the divContainer in pixel.

eg.

```
max-width: 710px;
```

Or you can also reduce max-width to 53%.I tried it works.

Comment: this works but the middle DIV doesnt fill the rest of the screen so bigger resolutions will have a empty space on the right of their screen

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all 3 columns in 1 div and set the min-width so that the entire page wont resize smaller than this.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a min-width + percentage for the middle div is a little error-prone.

How about trying something like this for the middle one?

```
<div class="divContainer" style="float: none; margin-left: 300px; margin-right: 300px">
    <div class="divContent">
{CENTER DIV CONTENT HERE}
    </div>
</div>
```

What your essentially doing here is specifically not floating the middle div (so that it's margins slide under the two other ones - and then margin out each side. This way you should get the most flexibility. If the right side still drops, you may need to change the order of the HTML so that the middle div comes after the right one.

Comment: this puts the middle and right div below each other and middle div has white space on top